# Is there a way to use public proxy service on Azure Worker Roles?

Tags: networking, proxy, azure-worker-roles

My goal is to use a proxy for outgoing Internet connections, and not to use the datacenter's IP directly (not to get blocked by the website on the other end).
And of course it would be nice to have a different IP per worker role instance.
PrivateIPs can be a good solution, just cannot figure out how it is possible to configure different IPs for different instances of the same role.

Comment: Have you checked the options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction#load-balancer-differences) for  distributing network traffic using Microsoft Azure?

Comment: I'm talking about outgoing connection, out of Azure, not into Azure.